# TableRow is null even though its been declared in XML

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, tablelayout

I have an XML file that declares this TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Then in my fragments onCreateView I find it by Id:

```
TableRow row1 = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);
TableRow row2 = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);
```

Then in some views onClick, I try to do this:

```
TextView nameView = new TextView(getActivity());
//sets the column to skip the first one
nameView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(i + 1));
nameView.setText(materialNames[i]);
row1.addView(nameView);
```

and it throws nullpointer for no reason. I used this exact same method to find other views from my XML and it worked fine, but for some reason it thinks that those TableRows are null. I tried cleaning the project. Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: Are you loading the correct fragment layout? It sounds like it does not exist in the fragment layout that you are using.

Comment: Yes I am, this isn't the first View i access this way from the XML

Comment: Try like this: TableRow row1 = (TableRow) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);

Comment: Tried it, still null.

Comment: is it nameView that is null?

Comment: No. I updated the code to include it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend found a solution to this problem. The row1 and row2 variables are first declared as global variables within my fragment. Then inside onCreateView instead of actually initializing them, I created new, local variables within the onCreateView method, with the same name as the global ones. This was incredibly hard to find, and was fixed like this:

```
row1 = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);
row2 = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);
```

I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: "incredibly hard to find" with an IDE => "Find usage"... wait? why my assignment is not in that list? (or with a debugger? but not really, just see the code) And anyway, this problem could be fixed very easly here if you provided more context. Keep it in mind next time. (don't take it as offence, it's just to improve your questions/answers)